# jQuery Plugin Skeleton

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Looking at jQuery's [Plugins/Authoring documentation](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/) I find some questions. I need to create a plugin that lets me do the following:

```
$('#one').plug({foo:'bar'});
$('#two').plug();
```

According  to the docs I should:

```
(function($){

    var settings = {
        foo:''
    };
    var methods = {
        init:function(options){
            return this.each(function(){
                $.extend(settings, options);

                //------ Problem ----------//
                alert(settings.foo);

            });
        }
    };
    $.fn.plug = function(method){
        //...
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Problem : `$('#one').plug({foo:'bar'});` alerts "bar" as expected but the next line doesn't return an empty string it return "bar" too.

Comment: Setting's obj isn't in the scope of your addon. If you go to the JS Console and type settings, you should get it. Which you actualyl shouldn't. You should read the documentation properly. Or you need to resete settings at some time.

Comment: What should I do if I need a value local to the plugin instance, set in the 'init' method through user default settings and accessable in other methods of the plugin instance?

Comment: If you want to have a vvariable outside of the scope of your addon, you are doing it right, actually. The reason why you get 'bar' again is because it is saved from the last call. Since settings isn't within the addon it doesn't get reseted (simply said). So you'd have to to settings = ''; or something similar at the start of you addon or make your var within your addon. I'm no crack in JS so you might ask in #jquery on freenode server (irc) there's a web chat for freenode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thought I should post this out for anyone with the same question. There are many ways to create a jQuery plugin. The one I now use frequently is a this skeleton:

```
(function($, window, document, undefined){

    function Skeleton(element, options){
        this.$element = $(element);
        this.options = options;

        // Plugin init goes here...

    }

    Skeleton.prototype = {
        // Plugin methods
        sampleMethod: function(){
            // ...
        }

    };
    // Plugin Definition //
    $.fn.skeleton = function(options){
        if( typeof options == 'string'){
            var plugin = this.data('skeleton');
            if(plugin){
                var r = plugin[options].apply(plugin, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ) );
                if(r) return r
            }
            return this
        }

        options = $.extend({}, $.fn.skeleton.defaults, options);

        return this.each(function(){
            var plugin = $.data(this, 'skeleton');
            if( ! plugin ){
                plugin = new Skeleton(this, options);
                $.data(this, 'skeleton', plugin);
            }
        });
    };
    $.fn.skeleton.defaults = {
        // Plugin options ...
    };

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Comment: Great skeleton, but towards the end you need to make a copty of the default options: 

> plugin = new CollapsiblePanel(this, $.extend({}, options));

Answer (score 0):

I use the following template for jquery plugins

```
(function($, window, document, undefined){
    $.fn.wolmVerticalSplitSlider = function(options) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            refreshFrequency: 5000,
        }, options );
        function Instance(comp){
            this.comp = comp;
        }
        Instance.prototype.init = function(){
            this.comp.html('Hello world!' + settings.refreshFrequency)
        }
        
        return this.each(function() {
            var component = new Instance($(this));
            component.init();
        });
    };

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

where **wolmVerticalSplitSlider** is plugin Name **refreshFrequency** is a plugin attribute

to use the plugin

```
$( document ).ready(
    function () {
        $('.vertical-slider').wolmVerticalSplitSlider({refreshFrequency: 1000});
    }
);
```